# Android System Tray Notification Handling via FCM

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending notification and data payload from my server and generating a notification in Android System tray. but if I want to remove particular notification if user read that conversation through app and not via clicking system tray item then how to find that notificationId to write code like notificationManager.Cancel(notificationId) and not notificationManager.CancelAll()

Comment: create an id in your data payload. Then use the id for the notification id.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך can you give me an example snippet?